# Application_Start not firing in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax, application-start

I've got an ASP.NET MVC app where the `Application_Start` event appears to not be firing. The symptoms are that an `NLog` log statement in that handler does not generate a log entry, and none of my routes get populated (so all my requests for controller actions return a 404).

Static files on the server (eg, favicon.ico) are served correctly.

I have log statements in `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest.` Those do generate log entries, both for the controller methods and the static files, so I feel pretty confident the app pool is configured correctly.

The problem shows up on our staging server, but not my local machine or our dev server.

Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: is it possible `restartOnExternalChanges` was changed in your staging box's machine.config?

Comment: Is there a chance that the log process simply fails when the `Application_Start` is fired? I think in `Application_Start` the `Session` object is not available

Comment: Have you tried recycling IIS?

Comment: I don't have permissions to machine.config, but I'm asking into that. I don't think it's likely that it's "simply" the log process failing in Application_Start, because 1) the actions return a 404, so the route population is also failing 2) the log process works in Application_Start on the dev server. There may be a single problem causing both the log fail and the route population fail; I don't know of a great way to distinguish that from the method not firing at all.

Comment: Yes, have tried recycling IIS - as well as changing web.config, rebuilding dll, restarting the app pool, and restarting the entire server.

Comment: Apparently restartOnExternalChanges is set to false (which seems odd), but that's the case on both dev and stage. And, I guess, that probably doesn't come into play once we got to the point of trying to restart the server.

Comment: Is an unhandled exception raised in your logging code which is causing the application to terminate? Are there any custom modules which are firing up, and raising an unhandled exception?

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a combination of things. The root cause was inconsistent versions of DLL's, and I solved that by configuring the project to copy the problem assemblies to my bin folder. On top of that, there was some code in Application_Error that was preventing the actual exception from being shown.

Comment: Hi.  I'm having the same issue, how did you fix the dll problem?